# Remove ?_ga=RANDOM_NUMBER from URL of wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, url, google-analytics

How do I do that? My website URL: https://thecourship.com and there is a menu named Services, if you click any of the sub-menus under Services section you can see the " ?_ga= " string with some random numbers. Please help me remove it. Thanks in advance. BTW this is wordpress website.

Comment: I see no such thing on my browser

Comment: Did you click the menus below Services from the main website?

Answer (score 0):

[Google Cross Domain Tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342) is enabled
[image]

Comment: How can I remove it?